# How to update Date when countdown reached 0 without refreshing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, countdown, jquery-countdown

I'm trying to get the date updated when countdown reached 0 without refreshing browser.

Here's the code

```
var tdy = new Date();
var nxt = new Date();
var dd = new Date();

tdy.setHours(16,00,0,0);
nxt.setHours(16,00,0,0);

var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "Jun";
month[6] = "Jul";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sep";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";
var mth = month[dd.getMonth()];

function doCountDown() {

    if(tdy <= nxt){ 
        nxt.setDate(nxt.getDate()+1);
        dd.setDate(dd.getDate()+3);

        if(dd.getHours() == 16){
            dd.setDate(dd.getDate()+1);
        }
    }

    $('#clock').countdown(nxt).on('update.countdown', function(event){

       $('#delivered-date').text(dd.getDate()+' '+mth+' '+dd.getFullYear());

        $(this).text(event.strftime('%H hr %M min %S sec'));

    })
    .on('finish.countdown', function(event){
        setTimeout(doCountDown, 1000);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    doCountDown();
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/2dot1geo/1/

To test if the date is updated, simply change the dd.getHours to dd.getMinutes and change the 2 setHours of var tdy and var nxt.

I have tested using the Minutes to see if the date updated without refreshing the browser but it doesn't.

Only after I refreshed the browser, then the date will updated.

So how can I alter this to work? I need to update the date when countdown reached 0 or it reached the time I want. No browser refresh.

FYI,
The date will +1 if hours equal to 16 if countdown reached 0 or it reached 1600 (4pm). So when it reached 4pm, the date should increment 1 day without browser refresh.

Comment: Well, `setTimeout()` expects a function as the first argument. It looks like you are passing it a jQuery selection (`$('#clock')`). That will not work. Also, why are you using `clearInterval()`? You are not using any intervals (timeouts are not the same as intervals).

Comment: I see. I have updated the jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/2dot1geo/1/, but still it doesn't update the date without refreshing browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this on my own. Feel free to reference this for your own use.

Here's my own answer.

Javascript:

```
    function spellMonth(mth){
    var month = new Array();
month[0] = "Jan";
month[1] = "Feb";
month[2] = "Mar";
month[3] = "Apr";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "Jun";
month[6] = "Jul";
month[7] = "Aug";
month[8] = "Sep";
month[9] = "Oct";
month[10] = "Nov";
month[11] = "Dec";
var m = month[mth];
    return m;
}

function doCountDown(){
    var nxt = new Date();
    nxt.setHours(nxt.getHours()<16?16:40,00,0,0);
    //nxt.setHours(21,57,0,0);

    var dd = new Date();
    dd.setDate(dd.getDate()+2);

    if(dd.getHours()>=nxt.getHours()){
    //if(dd.getMinutes()>=nxt.getMinutes()){
        dd.setDate(dd.getDate()+1);
    }
    else{
        dd.setDate(dd.getDate());
    }

    $('#date').html(dd.getDate()+' '+spellMonth(dd.getMonth())+' '+dd.getFullYear());

    return nxt;
}

$('#clock').countdown(doCountDown()).on('update.countdown', function(event){
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%H hr %M min %S sec'));
})
.on('finish.countdown', function(event){
   $(this).html(event.strftime('%H hr %M min %S sec'));
   $(this).countdown(doCountDown(), function(event){
      $(this).html(event.strftime('%H hr %M min %S sec'));        
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="clock"></div>
<div id="date"></div>
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/archampion/s4q1orwr/2/

As you can see the code is somewhat similar. But instead of putting the countdown in the doCountDown function, I return doCountDown as the date and time and put it as the countdown.

In doCountDown(), I created a new date, nxt, to check if today's hours is less than 16 (which is 4pm), hours set to 16, else set to 40 (which is the next day 4pm, 16hr + 24hr = 40hr). Since I want to countdown 24 hours, this is how I calculate and so I returning nxt as the countdown.

Additionally, I want to have a date showing to people. Initially, the date will show today's date +2. Then I check this date's hours (this is today's hours) against nxt's hours. If date's hours is larger or equal to nxt's hours (this was set to 1600 hours), I add one more day, else remaining the same.

For your info, the jquery countdown I'm using is from http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

So you see this line,

```
$(this).html(event.strftime('%H hr %M min %S sec'));
```

is on both update.countdown and finish.countdown.

If you just put this on update.countdown, the timer will stop at 1 second and then restart the countdown. This is kinda weird and may not look right because usually people would see all zeros in a countdown. So you have to put it on finish.countdown also. This it to tell the timer when countdown finished, update countdown to zeros, and then restart the countdown.

Anyone has any doubt, feel free to ask.